Chrome extension not working when DevTool open
When I open the Chrome devtool, I cannot open/use any extension already installed.
I have to close the devtool, use the extension like I want, then re-open devtool.
Weird: It works if I am on another chrome profile
Some months ago, I was able to use extension while the devtool is open.
Maybe I have done something wrong in my settings.. but I don't achieve to know/see what's is the error or something else.
Did someone has a way to fix to issue ?
Thanks

It's a bug in Chrome. Try changing chrome://flags/#devtools-tab-target

It doesn't work. Other clue: It works if I am on another chrome profile

Try comparing variations shown in chrome://version/?show-variations-cmd in both profiles.

The only difference is the Profile Path value

Would a chrome://settings/reset help? Or disabling and then re-enabling Chrome extensions? Did the issue persist when creating a new profile and gradually configuring it as your primary profile?

Go to the Devtools settings (clicking on the gear icon) and click on the "Restore Defaults and Reload" button.
I had the same problem and in this way I solved
